# Run another click method when element has inline onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am using gravity forms for WordPress, and onclick of an element I need to change the value of another input. The only problem is the element I need to click has an inline click function.

I still need to run both functions, is there anyway of achieving this?

Comment: You've said "before" in your title, but not in your question. Does the order matter?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder order doesnt particularly matter, either way should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter, you can add another click handler:

```
$("selector-for-the-element").on("click", function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

That doesn't affect the inline click handler at all. Depending on the browser, it will run either before or after the inline handler.

I think Wordpress tends to put your scripts in the `head` section of the document, which is unfortunate. I think it may also use "no conflict" mode and so `$` may not refer to jQuery. If so, you'll want to wrap that in a `ready` handler, which solves both problems, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("selector-for-the-element").on("click", function() {
        // Your code here
    });
});
```